# Condensing multidimensional array of permutations into groups

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in Ruby which looks like this:

```
[[1,12], [1,5], [1,6], [5,12], [6,12], [12,5], [12,6]]
```

I need to combine it into a new multidimensional array, grouping values together, to form valid combinations of (**n**) positions (**n** being the size of each element in the original array):

```
[
  [[1,5,6], [12]], # [1,5,6].product([12]) #=> [[1, 12], [5, 12], [6, 12]]
  [[1,12], [5,6]]  # [1,12].product([5,6]) #=> [[1, 5], [1, 6], [12, 5], [12, 6]]
]
```

The purpose of this is to take an array of **n**-place permutations, and generate the smallest possible multidimensional array that lists the valid numbers in each place (while not including combinations that aren't present in the original array).

How can a multidimensional array containing **n**-place permutations be reduced down to the array described above? The built-in (and brilliant) array methods in Ruby don't seem to include a function for this, and short of generating every possible combination and then testing them against the original permutations, I'm not sure how to get it right.

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind the expected output. You say you want to create combinations of 2 positions, yet the output has 3,1,2,2 as the length

Comment: Each item in the resulting array contains 2 arrays, one for each place, containing the valid entries for that place ([1,5,6] in the first position, [12] in the second position in the case of the first item, and [1,12] in first position, [5,6] in second position for the second item). If you look at all the possible permutations of 1,5,6 and 12, this pattern specifically excludes [5,6] and [6,5] from being valid permutations for 1st and 2nd, which is what I'm trying to do - express a limited list of permutations for n places in the format above.

Comment: @RichardWalker I've added two inline-comments based on your explanation (I hope I got it right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I correctly understand the problem, but given this array:

```
a = [[1, 12], [1, 5], [1, 6], [5, 12], [6, 12], [12, 5], [12, 6]]
```

I think you can group the left-hand items by the right-hand items:

```
h1 = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
a.each { |k, v| h1[v] << k }
h1
#=> {12=>[1, 5, 6], 5=>[1, 12], 6=>[1, 12]}
```

And apply the same transformation again:

```
h2 = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
h1.each { |k, v| h2[v] << k }
h2
#=> {[1, 5, 6]=>[12], [1, 12]=>[5, 6]}
```

This gives:

```
h2.to_a
#=> [
#     [[1, 5, 6], [12]],
#     [[1, 12], [5, 6]]
#   ]
```

In recent versions of Ruby you could write it as:

```
a.group_by(&:last).transform_values { |v| v.map(&:first) }
 .group_by(&:last).transform_values { |v| v.map(&:first) }
 .to_a
#=> [
#     [[1, 5, 6], [12]],
#     [[1, 12], [5, 6]]
#   ]
```

The condensed array can be expanded via:

```
[[[1, 5, 6], [12]], [[1, 12], [5, 6]]].flat_map { |a, b| a.product(b) }
#=> [[1, 12], [5, 12], [6, 12], [1, 5], [1, 6], [12, 5], [12, 6]]
```

Note that this attempt only works for sub-arrays with two elements, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thank you - that is precisely what I was trying to achieve! I'm looking at ways to do the same with sub-arrays with 3 elements, and this will be a great start (I may have to get creative with recursion).